# About limit of variable x y

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, functional-analysis, limits, analysis

Suppose $a>0,b>0,r=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$

1)proof $x^ay^b=o(r^l)(r\rightarrow 0),0<l<a+b$

$2)\lim_{(x,y)\rightarrow (0,0)}\frac{x^ay^b}{r^{a+b}} $exist or not

My attempt

1)$$\frac{x^ay^b}{r^l}=\frac{x^ay^b}{(x^2+y^2)^\frac{l}{2}}\le \frac{1}{2^l}\frac{x^ay^b}{(xy)^{\frac{l}{2}}}$$
And I don’t know what to do next

2)let $y=x$, $x\rightarrow 0$ then I get the limit is $$\frac{1}{2^{\frac{a+b}{2}}}$$

and I let $y=0,x\rightarrow 0$,I get the limit equal $0$ ,am I right?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your answer for 2) is correct. For i) use polar coordinates. $\frac {|x|^{a}|y|^{b}} {r^{ l }}=r^{a+b-l}  (|cos (\theta)|)^{a} (|sin (\theta)|)^{b}) \to 0$.

Comment: Sin($\theta)$’s power should be b?

Comment: @jackson Sure! Corrected.